# Regex with balancing groups works with negative lookahead but not positive lookahead (.net dialect)

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I posted an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050477/how-can-i-get-this-regex-right-in-c/42051553#42051553) where the OP wants a regex to match different blocks of JSON-esque data with a condition that one of the properties has a specific value.

Simplifying the question a little bit - assume some sample data like this:

```
layer { foo { bar { baz } } qux }
layer { fee { bar { baz } } qux }
layer { foo { bar { baz foo } } qux { quux quuux } }
{}
zip { layer { zop { layer {yeehah { foo } } } } }
zip { layer{ zop { layer {yeehah { fee } } } } }
```

The regex should match for `layer { .. stuff with nested data ...}` but only where there is a data-element of `foo`.

My regex in the answer is:

`layer\s*{(?>{(?<c>)|[^{}](?!fee)+|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))}`

Which instead of positively identifying matches containing `foo` just excludes those containing `fee`. That is fine if all non-`fee`-items are `foo`-items but that wasn't the case for the question on the other thread. My solution basically adds all the other non-`foo`-items to the negative lookahead like this:

`layer\s*{(?>{(?<c>)|[^{}](?!fee|blah|bloh|bluh|etc)+|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))}`

But this is impractical if you do not know in advance the data items you want to exclude. I tried using a positive lookahead:

`layer\s*{(?>{(?<c>)|[^{}](?=foo)+|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))}`

But that does not work.

My question: can anyone help me re-write the regex to match for the e.g. `layer { foo { bar } }` items by using a positive lookahead - or do I need to use something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the positive lookahead, use capturing and stack with conditional check:

```
layer\s*{(?<f>\s*foo)?(?>{\s*foo(?<f>)(?<c>)|{(?<c>)|[^{}]+|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))(?(f)|(?!))}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=layer%5cs*%7b%28%3f%3cf%3e%5cs*foo%29%3f%28%3f%3e%7b%5cs*foo%28%3f%3cf%3e%29%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%7c%7b%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%7c%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%7c%7d%28%3f%3c-c%3e%29%29*%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%28%3f%28f%29%7c%28%3f!%29%29%7d&i=layer+%7b+foo+%7b+bar+%7b+baz+%7d+%7d+qux+%7d%0d%0alayer+%7b+fee+%7b+bar+%7b+baz+%7d+%7d+qux+%7d%0d%0alayer+%7b+foo+%7b+bar+%7b+baz+foo+%7d+%7d+qux+%7b+quux+quuux+%7d+%7d%0d%0a%7b%7d%0d%0azip+%7b+layer+%7b+zop+%7b+layer+%7byeehah+%7b+foo+%7d+%7d+%7d+%7d+%7d%0d%0azip+%7b+layer%7b+zop+%7b+layer+%7byeehah+%7b+fee+%7d+%7d+%7d+%7d+%7d)

POIs:

- `layer\s*{(?<f>\s*foo)?` - an optional named group "f" is added that captures `foo` if present after the `layer {` + optional number of whitespaces.
- `(?>{\s*foo(?<f>)(?<c>)|` - the first branch inside the atomic group is a branch that matches a `{` (start of a node) that is followed with `foo`, and if matched, 2 stacks are incremented: `f` (foo group) and `c` (open brace group).
- `(?(f)|(?!))` - after the balanced number of `{` and `}` is checked, this conditional construct checks if the foo stack is not empty, and if it is not empty, all is OK, the match is returned, if not, the match is failed.